# CSS3 prefixes statement for rounded corners in all brosers

Tags: css

The future of border-radius is defined like so below:

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

But all the prefixes are specific:

```
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
```

Are these prefixes correct?  Is there a way to write the future tag and have the prefixes compiled?

Comment: This may help. http://lessprefixer.com/

Comment: I usually use http://css3generator.com/, which creates the main ones all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

- Firefox supported vendorless `border-radius` since 4.0.  Before that, use `-moz`.
- Chrome and Safari needed `-webkit` both in 4.0, but not after.
- `-o` apparently never existed; Opera has supported vendorless `border-radius` for some time now.

I think that non-vendor-prefixed `border-radius` is fine now.